# Strange output with _ _ FILE _ _ macro

Tags: c++, winapi

Why is the macro `__FILE__` expanded to the full name of the file with the path included on the one computer and to the name of the file only (without path specified)? On both computers I have MSVC-10.0 and Win7.

Of course, standard doesn't guarantee anything about it:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

> 16.8 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]
>
> `__FILE__` The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal).

MSDN says the following about this macro:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

> `__FILE__`
>
> The name of the current source file. `__FILE__` expands to a string surrounded by double quotation marks.

I don't use key /FC on both computers.

Comment: does it happen to same project?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im No, but all the settings look the same

Comment: /FC matters.  It is forced on when you compile with /ZI.

Comment: Since they're both names of the current source file, there's nothing wrong at the compiler level.  There must be some critical difference in the way the projects are set up; some compilation option or other IDE setting.

Comment: The compiler would presumably need to encode the entire path if the file was added with a non-relative reference, and it were keeping source file names unique. I don't suppose there's a standard guarantee that they should be, but it seems a worthy cause.

Comment: Is the compiler's working directory the same in both cases?  Perhaps the file's basename is used if the compiler happens to be run from that file's directory.